# How do a run a search with returns by the highest average

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to return a table and descend from the highest average of runs to the lowest for each player using Laravel 5.4

I have two tables

```
**Player**: id, Name, Nationality, accepted
**Batting_innings**: Id, runs, player_id
```

models:

```
class Player extends Model
{

   public function batIngs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\battingIns','player_id');
    }
}
```

in my controller currently i am using this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    //
    $bat = Player::all();

    $batsmen =Player::where('accepted', '=', 1)->orderBy($bat->batIngs->avg('runs');

    $batsmen=$batsmen->paginate(10);
    return view('pages.search')->with('batsmen', $batsmen)

}
```

I get the error that batIngs isnt found. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can't call `batIngs` on Collection returned by `Player::all()`.

Comment: have u done php artisan migrate?

Comment: Yes the tables are migrated. If i cannot get it through Player:all() how do i return the avg and order by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot order by a collection or any external resource, you need to provide a queried or calculated field within the very same query, in you case you need to use `DB::raw()` to calculate the field, the average of runs of the player, for that I would use the query builder:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    // Add fields to the select method as you need them
    $result = \DB::table('Player')
        ->join('Batting_innings', 'Player.id', '=', 'Batting_innings.player_id')
        ->select(\DB::raw('Player.id, AVG(Batting_innings.runs) as average_runs'))
        ->where('accepted', '=', 1)
        ->groupBy('Player.id')
        ->orderBy('average_runs','desc')
        ->paginate(10);

    // Turn the collection of arrays into a collection of Player models
    $batsmen = Player::hydrate($result->toArray());  

    return view('pages.search')->with('batsmen', $batsmen)

}
```

Hope this helped you.

Comment: This was good man but think i never got around the pagination error as you cannot use group by and paginator? so how would i work around that?